# XMLHttpRequest - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am uploading a file with laravel and using ajax request to create the progress bar for it. 
This is how the form action routes to the controller:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('upload-file-form-post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.
.
</form>
```

ajax:

```
function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadfile() {
  var file = _("file").files[0];
  // dev
  alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+ " | "+" | "+file.type);
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "here_is_where_the_url_needs_to_go");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
   _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + "bytes of "+ event.total;
   var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
   _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
   _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
```

is there a way to send this 
`{{ URL::route('upload-file-form-post') }}`to the ajax request?

in my routes file the above is referenced as:

```
Route::post('/asset/upload-file', array(
    'as'  => 'upload-file-form-post',
    'uses' => 'AssetController@postUploadCreate'
));
```

Comment: Is your AJAX code really global (directly inside of `<script>` tags)? Or is that triggered in an event? Such as the form being submitted? That would make it a lot easier to get the `action`

Comment: full js code updated, it's being trigger onclick event `onclick="uploadfile()"`

Comment: Do you want to use the `url/route` in your `js` code ? What is the `view` that loads this page ?

Comment: @cchacholiades The event `onclick` bind on what element?

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Upload file" onclick="uploadfile()">`. The view that load this page? I am not sure what you ask me about , its a view that extends the main blade layout.

Comment: yes, i want to use the url/route in js code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use JavaScript to get the form action attribute

```
//Whatever your action value
var action = document.formName.getAttribute('action');
```

**First:**

Don't mix `onclick` event on submit button, clicking submit button actually process the form itself. Its better to bind submit events to forms instead of binding click events on submit button.

By giving a `name` attribute to your form like `name="my_form"`, you can add submit event handler to your form.

**Like this:**

```
document.my_form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var actionURL = this.action; // will get the form action url
    uploadfile(actionURL); // your upload event with request url
});
```

Your function `uploadfile(..)` will accept a parameter called URL. Which will be passed to `ajax.open(..)` method

**Modified:**

```
// -----------------!!!! pass parameter for url
function uploadfile(url) {
  var file = _("file").files[0];
  // dev
  alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+ " | "+" | "+file.type);
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", url); // your url will pass to open method
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

**Edited:**

To fix Laravel Mismatch token issue [(Referrence)](http://www.keltdockins.com/2/post/2013/09/laravel-4-csrf-token-and-ajax-using-jquery.html):

Add below `<meta >` tag within your `<head>` tag of your current form view file.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>">
```

Or use blade

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">
```

Now within your `uploadfile(...)` function add this snippet:

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
    if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == "csrf-token") {  
        ajax.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", metas[i].getAttribute("content"));
    } 
}
```

See updated JavaScript code from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xM8Rn/2/)

Comment: @cchacholiades It will submit the form only once. By the way see my edit.

Comment: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
Is it because i added the meta tag in my main.blade.php instead of the current view ?

Comment: @cchacholiades Place the for loop after `ajax.open(..)` method. See update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xM8Rn/3/)

Comment: @cchacholiades This is correct. `url` within the function is just a placeholder.